# How to extend a Django form in template?

Tags: django, forms, templates, extend

I have an html base file of `step0.html`. I extend it with

```
{% extends "step0.html" %}
```

all it's good but only my Django form not extends.
Only the `"following size"` and `"max number of modalities"` are django form

[step0.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XTMD.png)

[step1.html with extends step0 for header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWCzI.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: Upload `views.py` in your Question

Comment: Please do not show us the image of your code. Share the exact code so that we can easily copy-paste the code and try it on our machines.

Comment: the code is way too long.., but normally the exetend is supposed to inherit also the django form yes or no? please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.